# Shrinking the Logo when Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

In simple terms, I require my Logo to shrink when I hit the slide show as seen in the Image.

[image: The Slideshow is where I want it to shrink.]

But I cannot seem to get the jQuery to work. Can someone please show me how I could shrink something such as the Logo seen the image above without affecting the tabs to it's right? I will be able to edit the size according to my preference once I know how to shrink the logo.

Here is the Code for the Navigation Bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="opacity: 0.8;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
    <a class="logo" href="School%20Home.html"><img style="padding-left: 100px; height: 120px; width: 235px;" src="https://s24.postimg.org/o3c7li4mt/Screen_Shot_2017-04-18_at_8.15.25_AM.png" alt="Human Rights Council Homepage"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li style="font-size: 12.5px;"><a href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12.5px;"><a href="United%20Nations.html">UNITED NATIONS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="font-size: 12.5px;">HUMAN RIGHT VIOLATIONS IN MYANMAR
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #0099ff; padding: 10px; width: 700px; height: 470px; color: white; box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);">

              <table style="width: 100%;">
                 <tr> 
                  <th style="border-right: 1px solid white; padding: 10px;"><strong><a href="Human%20Right%20Activists%20Criminals.html">Human Right Activists Criminals</a></strong></th>
                  <th style="border-left: 1px solid white; padding-left: 20px;"><strong>Human Right Activists are facing prison time in Myanmar due to their Efforts in stoping Human Right Violations.</strong></th>
                  </tr>

                  <tr> 
                      <th style="border-right: 1px solid white; border-top: 1px solid white; padding: 10px;"><strong><a href="Illegal%20Land%20Confiscations.html">Illegal Land Confiscations in Myanmar</a></strong></th>
                  <th style="border-left: 1px solid white; border-top: 1px solid white; padding-left: 20px;"><strong>Illegal Land Confiscations without proper compensation are leaving the citizens of Myanmar Homeless and with little resources.</strong></th>
                  </tr>
              </table>

          </ul>
        </li>
      <li style="font-size: 12.5px;"><a href="COMMING%20SOON.html">DONATE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The Css for the Navigation Bar is located inside the code above in the tag `Style`.
Here is the CSS:

```
 body {
     padding-top: 13%;
     padding-right: 20px;
     padding-left: 10px;
 }   

.navbar {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border-radius: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: black!important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: black!important;
    background-color: white!important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff!important;
}

/* Add a dark background color with a little bit see-through */ 
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 70px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    opacity:0.9;

}

/* Controls normal color of nav bar */
.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand { 
    color: black;
}

/* On hover, the links will turn black */
.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

/* The active link */
.navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: White!important;
    background-color:blue!important;
}

/* Remove border color from the collapsible button */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
}

/* Dropdown */
.open .dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

/* Dropdown links */
.dropdown-menu li a {
    color: #000000 !important;
    font-size: 15px;
}

/* On hover, the dropdown links will turn white */
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0099ff;
}
```

I also use a lot of Stylesheets which define's the look of the Navigation Bar:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="shrink.js">
```

Heres my Jquery:

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 0,
            .logo = document.querySelector(".logo");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(.logo,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(.logo,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(.logo,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Comment: *"But I cannot seem to get the Jquery to work"* what jquery? I don't see any JS in your code.

Comment: You  might be looking for `transform: scale(.5)` where `.5` is the amount you want it to scale - that will shrink a thing while keeping the space the element occupies the same so it shouldn't affect the layout of other elements around it.

Comment: This looks like an issue to me: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="shrink.js">`  This should be wrapped in a `<script>` tag...or your extension needs to be `.css` instead of `.js`

Comment: I have added the jquery i used the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

What happens now in your code is that when you scroll it either adds or remove the class "**smaller**" to your logo. 
Which means that if you put the following rule in your css the logo image will change to whatever size you set in this css rule. Your original settings are height: 120px width: 235px.

```
.logo.smaller img {
    height: 80px !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

You should probably edit your padding or whatever to have the desired position as well.
I added **!important** to make sure that it will override your other styles.

I would write the jquery part like this:

`function resizeLogo() {
    /* set after which point you want to change the logo. I set it when the scroll is more than your navbar height but you can set it to a numeric value e.g 100 or bind it to an element by an id */
    var offset = parseInt($(".navbar").height());
    var duration = 500;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            $(".logo").addClass("smaller");
        } else {
            if ($(".logo").hasClass("smaller")) {
                $(".logo").removeClass("smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}`

Then call it with:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeLogo();
});`

Comment: Thx for your reply Stavros, But I still can't seem to get it shrink. Is there something I need to change in the Js to make it shrink when i scroll or reach the slideshow in the image above? the class of the slide show div is "carousel slide".

Comment: I edited my response and added how I would write the javascript part. So if you use this, if you inspect your .logo source you will notice that when the page is scrolled the extra class smaller is added or removed accordingly.

Comment: I am possibly doing something wrong but it's still not working - I replaced the Javascript i had with the one you suggested and placed the "call it with" in the actual HTML document using script tags. But it just won't shrink. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are not loading the jquery library correctly. You should use your browser's developer tools to check for errors. If you have a live link I could tell you what's really wrong.